# javascript: remove specific text from url

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, url, parameters

i'm trying to make right click> search by image for website, but source images will be 1 specific website only, so website needs only "images1/image1" from "http://example.com/images1/img1.jpg"

```
var url = 'example.com/search/';

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(info, tab){
    chrome.tabs.create({
        url: url + encodeURIComponent(info.srcUrl),
        index: tab.index + 1
    })
});
var onInitialize = function(){
    chrome.contextMenus.create({
        title: 'Search by image',
        contexts: ['image'],
        targetUrlPatterns: ['https://*/*', 'http://*/*'],
        id: 'contextMenu'
    });
};
```

this code results in "example.com/search/https://sourceimageexample.com/images/img1.jpg"
it should look like "example.com/search/images1/img1/
solutions i found online didn't work or i couldn't make it work, any help? xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this to trim the end of the line:

```js
let line = 'image/image.jpg';
const suffix = '.jpg';
const result = line.substring(0, line.length - suffix.length);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick regex that would work for *most* addresses.

```js
// Paste this into regexr.com if you need help understanding exactly what it does.   
let regex = /(https|http):\/\/((\d+\.?)+|((?:()|www.)[0-z]+\.[a-z]+))\//g;
 
let url = "https://examp1e.com/images/article1/img1.jpg";
url = url.replace(regex, "");
url = url.substring(0, url.lastIndexOf("."));

console.log(url);
// prints 'images/article1/img1'
```

The above regex will also match numerical IPs, so `https://127.0.0.1/images/img1` would work as expected.

Now, this regex will not match any domains with non-latin characters, but you likely won't come across one anyway. It's all a matter of using the 90/10 rule to your advantage.

Disclaimer: I really am not the best at writing regular expressions, so do correct me if I've done something incorrectly/badly.

Comment: @Sinnerman I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you're saying.

Comment: @Sinnerman Yeah, I'm not going to spoon-feed you. You'll need to figure out how to incorporate this snippet in your code yourself.